# Nested case with multiple sub conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm having trouble to understand how to nest case statements properly.
(MSSQL Server 2012)

Let's have the following table given. 
The Column StatusMissing is what I want to create

```
+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
|  a1  |  |  a2  |  |  a3  |  |  b1  |  |  c1  |  |  d2  |  | StatusMissing |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | AllOK         |
| NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | As            |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | As            |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | As            |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | B             |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | C             |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | D             |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | ABC           |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | ACD           |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | ABD           |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | ABCD          |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | ACD           |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | BC            |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | AllOK         |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | AC            |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | BD            |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | CD            |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
```

First, to understand the concept of nesting I simplified the table:

```
+------+--+------+--+------+
|  a1  |  |  a2  |  |  b1  |
+------+--+------+--+------+
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |
| NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |
+------+--+------+--+------+
```

These attempts lead to these failures.
Query1

```
SELECT a1, a2, b1 'StatusMissing' =
CASE 
        WHEN a1 IS NULL
        THEN 
                CASE
                        WHEN a1 IS NULL
                        THEN 
                                CASE
                                        WHEN b1 IS NULL
                                        THEN 'AB'
                                END
                        ELSE 'A'
                END

        WHEN b1 IS NULL
        THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'AllOK'
END
FROM Table;
```

Result1:

```
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
|  a1  |  |  a2  |  |  b1  |  | StatusMissing |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | AllOK         |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | B             |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | AllOK         |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL          |
| NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL          |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | AB            |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | B             |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
```

Query2 (Else as main)

```
SELECT a1, a2, b1, 'Status' =
CASE 
        WHEN a1 IS NOT NULL AND a2 IS NOT NULL AND b1 IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'AllOK!'
        ELSE
                CASE
                        WHEN a2 IS NOT NULL OR a2 IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 
                                CASE
                                        WHEN b1 IS NULL
                                        THEN 'AB'
                                END

                        WHEN b1 IS NULL
                        THEN 'B'

                        ELSE 'A'
                END
END
FROM Table;
```

Result2

```
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
|  a1  |  |  a2  |  |  b1  |  | StatusMissing |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
| OK   |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | AllOK         |
| OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | AB            |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | A             |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | OK   |  | NULL          |
| NULL |  | NULL |  | OK   |  | A             |
| NULL |  | OK   |  | NULL |  | AB            |
| OK   |  | NULL |  | NULL |  | B             |
+------+--+------+--+------+--+---------------+
```

What the hell am I doing wrong?
I'm quite new to SQL, so if there is a proper function to do this I would appreciate the info!
EDIT:
If something like this would be possible in SQL i mean:
Column StatusMissing = ' missing'
If(a1 == NULL) { StatusMissing += 'A'}

EDIT2:

The column StatusMissing IS NOT THERE!
I want to create it using the SQL statements like below.
SELECT .... Status =

So basically I only have A1,A2,B1 (in the simple table). Please don't get confused with the first Table. It's only there to SHOW HOW IT SHOULD look like.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?:)

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to check if a field contains a NULL-Value. If so, then StatusMissing should tell me this. Like in the first table. There i manually added how my result should be displayed. :)

Comment: I would suggest you build a result matrix in a new table and join on it to get your result.

Comment: Sorry but how can this help me? In reality I have hundreds of rows. So you suggest me to manually check the status and type them in a extra table? Or did i misunderstood you?

Comment: Rouglhy this, yes. It's only advisable if you have a limited set of columns, or a limited set of results. You will build a table with the static version of your result set, and join your current table to this matrix.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how to do this? Yet - there isn't the possibility to achieve my goal with using CASE? Because somehow I am getting results, but they seem buggy somehow...

Comment: Actually there is a solution combining some `CASE` statements, I've added is as a distinct reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest that you make two small modifications to your output:

- Instead of "As", just say "A".
- Instead of "AllOK", just leave the field blank.

With these modifications, the rules are pretty easy:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when a1 is null or a2 is null or a3 is null then 'A' else '' end) +
        (case when b1 is null then 'B' else '' end) +
        (case when c1 is null then 'C' else '' end) +
        (case when d1 is null then 'D' else '' end)
       ) as StatusMissing
from table t;
```

If you do want your version, a subquery is perhaps the easiest way:

```
select t. . . .,
       (case when StatusMissing = '' then 'AllOK'
             when StatusMissing = 'A' then 'As'
             else StatusMissing
        end) as StatusMissing
from (select t.*,
             ((case when a1 is null or a2 is null or a3 is null then 'A' else '' end) +
              (case when b1 is null then 'B' else '' end) +
              (case when c1 is null then 'C' else '' end) +
              (case when d1 is null then 'D' else '' end)
             ) as StatusMissing
      from table t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Gordon! For my test table this worked perfectly. I've learned how to use this now. So this answer is the best!

Answer (score 1):

For the simplified table, assuming data type to be `nvarchar`.

Try using `UPDATE`-

```
  UPDATE [dbo].[StatusMissing]
  SET result='';

  UPDATE [dbo].[StatusMissing]
  SET result= CONCAT(result , 'A')
  WHERE a1 is null or a2 is null;


  UPDATE [dbo].[StatusMissing]
  SET result= CONCAT(result , 'B')
  WHERE b1 is null ;

  UPDATE [dbo].[StatusMissing]
  SET result= 'AllOK'
  WHERE result ='';
```

This can be done in one step as well.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry to confused you guys. To clearify my question please see EDIT2. The column StatusMissing is not there. It is being created using Select... 'StatusMissing' =

Comment: my bad, understood it wrong, I think you are just reporting on the basis of the table and so need cases. +Gordon's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `COALESCE` and a couple of `CASE` conditions

```
SELECT a1,
  a2,
  a3,
  b1,
  c1,
  d2,
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN 
      b1 = 'OK' 
      AND c1 = 'OK' 
      AND d2 = 'OK' 
      AND (a1 IS NULL OR a2 IS NULL OR a3 is NULL) 
    THEN 'As' 
    ELSE ''
    END,
    CASE WHEN 
      (a1 IS NULL OR a2 IS NULL or a3 is NULL) 
    THEN 'A' 
    END  
    + CASE WHEN 
        b1 IS NULL 
      THEN 'B'
      ELSE '' 
      END
    + CASE WHEN 
        c1 IS NULL 
      THEN 'C'
      ELSE '' 
      END 
    + CASE WHEN 
        d2 IS NULL 
      THEN 'D' 
      ELSE ''
    END,
    'AllOK') AS 'StatusMissing'
FROM Table;
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. All resulst are displayed as AllOK, except of where ALL are missing. :/

Comment: Might be because I forgot the else statements. Meanwhile, @Gordon Linoff solution is more elegant than mine.